# ¿Cómo puedo consultar obviando los valores NULL?

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta que me permita filtrar por DNI pero que no me obtenga los valores vacíos o `nulls`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE DNI LIKE '%214%' AND DNI IS NOT NULL AND DNI!=''`

Comment: quiza no me explique bien quiero q cuando ingrese el DNI me muestre los datos como en la tabla de abajo sin los nulos

Comment: @LUISICA a ver si lo he entendido bien, ¿lo que quieres es que el número de columnas que devuelva sea variable no? es decir que si todas las filas tienen C1003 un valor NULL, directamente no se devuelva la columna C1003 ¿no?

Comment: Como poder se puede, pero es algo antinatural para SQL, es algo que en todo caso deberías resolver desde la vista. Por otro lado ¿Has intentado resolverlo de alguna manera? si es así, agrega el código de lo que hayas probado.

Comment: Ten en cuenta, que lo que pides solo seria posible si lo que devuelve la consulta es un unico ROW.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar `IFNULL`

se usa asi:

```
SELECT IFNULL(columna, '') FROM......
```

Si `columna` fuera `null` lo substituye por `''` (blanco)

Comment: Me parece que lo que se busca es directamente no mostrar las columnas que tienen NULL

Comment: pues si es asi, es necesario una tabla pivot.

Comment: intente con pivot pero no encuentro la forma ademas en ese caso son solo 4 clumnas en las q evalua pero en mi BD tengo minimo 50 entonces creo q complica un poco el codigo